# Tasktracker logs

Tags: logging, hadoop, mapreduce

when i try to view logs of tasktracker i am facing below error...

can any one pls help me out:

> Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname)
>
> Your requested host "d04-7d-7b-a5-e9-2e.hdfs.target.com" could not
>   be resolved by DNS.
>
> For assistance, contact your network support team.
>
> Your request was categorized by Blue Coat Web Filter as 'Shopping'. 
>   If you wish to question or dispute this result, please click here.

Answer (score 0):

You have your HDFS configuration messed up.  Do you actually work for target?  If not then you should never have a hostname with target.com domain name.

If you do,  your Bluecoat configuration is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace "d04-7d-7b-a5-e9-2e.hdfs.target.com" with IP address of that machine. That should solve your problem . Or edit hosts file to DNS name and ip address.